# Reassign prefab in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to reassign a prefab to a GameObject?   I removed a prefab because the prefab attached script was removed and was throwing a warning. I was unable to remove the script from the inspector and save it, so I had to remove the prefab.

[image]

Comment: Maybe by editing the scene file with a text editor and reassigning the new prefab id. But I'm not sure it's a good idea. Insteed you can do a custom editor tool to explore the hierarchy and create a prefab for each gameobject, rename it, and copy the transform position if require. It's a bit of work but it's rewarding to make Unity work for you on boring task like this.

Comment: There is an asset in the store I think it’s search and replace. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

If they are made from the same prefab, what you can do is: **Drag one object from hierarchy to "Project" as you would create a new prefab from the existing "missing" prefab.**

This would ensure that they have a new parent prefab - with the same GUID as previously.

One downside would be that it revert the names of all prefabs in the scene you are currently in, to the new prefab name.

NOTE: This would not work if you closed the scene or Unity.

**EDIT:**

You can also modify scene manually by assigning `m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 665558973}` to the same ID for all your GameObjects. GameObjects with missing prefab would have `fileID: 0`.

You need to do this for all components probably (GameObject, Transform, Components etc). Make sure you have backup before trying this though.